# Tabula Py Stealing focus in Windows

Tags: java, python

In the FAQ section of tabula-py, there is a interesting question:

> Q: [I want to prevent tabula-py from stealing focus on every call on my mac](https://tabula-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#i-want-to-prevent-tabula-py-from-stealing-focus-on-every-call-on-my-mac)
>
> A: Set java_options=["-Djava.awt.headless=true"]. kudos @jakekara

But I am not able to get this to work in windows.

What is the right way to get this done in Windows?

*(I am struggling with constant popups every 10 secs and I have 3000 pdfs to parse.)*